# Unable to launch Asyc Job In Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I want to make a rest service which can invoke Spring Batch asynchronously, so that I can once start the job and it can run in background and HTTP connection can be closed.

I am using JobOperator to launch job with following configuration:

```
@Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(10);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor);
        return jobLauncher;
    }


    @Bean
    public JobOperator jobOperator() {
        SimpleJobOperator jobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();
        jobOperator.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
        jobOperator.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher());
        jobOperator.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        jobOperator.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return  jobOperator;
    };
```

With above configuration, I cannot launch the job the way I want. [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html#configuringJobLauncher) i read that we can launch job in different thread but not observed. Any Idea why such behavior is observed?

Comment: What exactly is happening? Is your REST service waits till Job completes? As your configuration seems correct for async JobLauncher.

Comment: Yes, it waits for the job to complete, and then returns the response.

Comment: Have you tried adding log with currentThread in your REST controller as well as in reader, processor or writer of your step inside the job? This will help you understand better. I have the same configuration in my project and it works just fine.

Comment: Yes, I tried. It seems that they are executing on the same thread. When Spring starts, I see a log: No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.

Comment: Interestingly, I am getting same log which says no TaskExecutor has been set. But it still creates new thread for the Job as per my configured `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`.

Comment: You are starting batch from Controller? And now? And are you adding any other configuration than this?

Comment: Mine is not MVC project but a simple standalone one. But still, it works as expected and creates new thread for Job execution. Not sure about that log though.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution. problem was in declaration of the the bean. The `JobLauncher` bean was getting overridden by the default implementation of spring batch. I did following renaming and it worked as expected:

```
@Bean
public SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher() {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(simpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
    return jobLauncher;
}

public SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor() {
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(10);
    return simpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
}

@Bean
public JobOperator jobOperator() {
    SimpleJobOperator jobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();
    jobOperator.setJobLauncher(simpleJobLauncher());
    jobOperator.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
    jobOperator.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
    jobOperator.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    return  jobOperator;
};
```